# Parent state also calling while child state loading

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

app.js

```
 var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.router']);

    itaasContentApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');

        $stateProvider.state('parent', {
            url:'/parent',
            templateUrl :'partials/parent.html',
            controller:'parentCtrl'
        })
          .state('parent.child',{
            url:'/child',
            templateUrl :'partials/child.html',
            controller  :'childCtrl'
        });
```

parent.html

```
<div ui-view>

<table data-ng-init='init()'>

</table>

</div>
```

child.html

```
<div >

<table data-ng-init='init()'>

</table>

</div>
```

parentCtrl

```
app.controller('parentCtrl', function($scope,$state) {

$scope.init=function()
{
//it will initialize the controller <html data-ng-init='init()'>
}
//I am calling child state
$state.go("parent.child");

});
```

childCtrl

```
 app.controller('childCtrl', function($scope,$state) {

    $scope.init=function()
    {
    //it will initialize the controller <html data-ng-init='init()'>

    }


    });
```

**Problem:**
While loading the child state init method parent init method also calling

init() of parent
then 
init() of child

can you please explain me where i did wrong

Comment: Yes...that's how parent/child states work. You shouldn't use `ng-init` either the way you are...see `ng-init` docs. Call your `init()` right in controller

Comment: @charlietfl could you please elaborate more
if possible using Plunker

Comment: if i follow above approach then parent init()  method is not calling when i navigate from child state to parent

Comment: In parent.html you have enclosed the table with in <div ui-view>. put the table out of this closing div tag.